# refresh chromium browser by shell script with xdotool via PHP

Tags: lxde, web-browsers, chromium, php, lighttpd

I want to refresh the browser, like pressing the F5 or Ctrl+F5 key on the keyboard with a shell script.

I´m new in writing shell scripts so i aks you to help me with this:

when I type in this into the command line, the refresh works perfectly:

```
DISPLAY=:0 xdotool getactivewindow key F5
```

I wrote a script refresh.sh with this content:

```
export DISPLAY=:0.0
xdotool getactivewindow
xdotool key F5
```

But it reurns:

```
pi@babaloo ~ $ sudo sh /var/www/refresh.sh
No protocol specified
Error: Can't open display: (null)
Failed creating new xdo instance
No protocol specified
Error: Can't open display: (null)
Failed creating new xdo instance
```

can someone give me a hint?

Chromium Browser is in Kiosk mode, here is my

```
/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE/autostart
```

-

```
#@lxpanel --profile LXDE
#@pcmanfm --desktop --profile LXDE
#@xscreensaver -no-splash
@xset s off
@xset -dpms
@xset s noblank
@chromium --kiosk --incognito http://localhost/output/output.php?monitor=1
```

~~ EDIT:

I changed my script to

```
export DISPLAY=:"0.0"
XAUTHORITY=/home/pi/.Xauthority
xdotool getactivewindow
xdotool key F5
```

when i start it from console with

```
sh /var/www/refresh.sh
```

it works!

But now i want to execute this script by PHP with user www-data. Therefor i added to **visudo:**

```
www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /var/www/refresh.sh
```

and Created a PHP-File with this content:

```
<?php
exec("sudo sh /var/www/refresh.sh");
?>
<h1>Refreshing output</h1>
```

But nothing happend...

Is there a chance to get more informations about the returning errors?
I found nothing in documentation for "exec"-command.

Also tried:

```
<?php
$output = array();
$output[] = exec("sudo sh /var/www/refresh.sh");
print_r($output)
?>
```

but the returning array is empty

Comment: It might be because you run your script as root.

Comment: theres no difference when I run it without sudo

Comment: Why do you run PHP exec to refresh a web page. That is so overkill! Just use Javascript to refresh the page `window.location.reload(false);` -You use a timer, or ajax to control when to refresh.  Since you have PHP running to execute the page you are viewing I assume the page you want to refresh is your page...

Comment: I have a lot of JS stuff in the browser and I need a "real" browser refresh (without javascript). This should clear the DOM. Another posibility is to close the browser with `killall chromium` and restart the application after... but i thin it´s a more "overkill".

Comment: meta refresh tag ?

Comment: I dont want to refresh the page with an intervall, i want to refresh it when i go to an browser at a other computer, type in the pi´s ip-adress, go to an HTML-site an press a button "refresh output now!"

Comment: I would use AJAX to do that then. Setup a webserver elsewhere, get the Pi to periodically check a page on that webserver. If that page has a value of 1, refresh.

Comment: It seems like whaty you are doing is flawed because if you struggling to do it its a good indication of how not to do it. Tell us what you are doing and we can possibly help you. Refreshing the page using meta or javascript is as good as F5. I do it all the time, the True in javascript forces a cache flush just like CTRL+F5. So ...?!

Answer (score 1):

I used a mix with PHP and jQuery Ajax now. I write a parameter into a Databas, if its "0", nothing will happen, if it is "1" the page relaods.

```
   var times = 0;

    var refreshId = window.setInterval(function(){
      // check refresh!
      $.ajax({
        type : "GET",
        url : "check.php",
        cache : false,
        success: function(data){
          var data = $.parseJSON(data);
          var refresh = data.refresh;

          if(refresh == 1){
            location.reload();
          }
...
```

Comment: use `location.reload(true)` to force the cache to be dropped and load the freshest data. like CRTL+F5. You should mark your answer as solved.

Comment: thanks, I already solved the caching problem in the document header, but your solution is also good!

Answer (score 1):

I achieve to do this by creating a dummy file on the folder, and making the php check if that file exists.

1.- My website has a time interval to check it ever

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      setInterval(checkRefresh, 10000);    
 });

function checkRefresh()
{
    $.ajax({
            url: "checkrefresh.php"
    }).done(function (response) {
        if (response == 1)
        {
          document.location.reload(true);          
        }
    });
}
```

2.- In an administrative website, I have a button to launch the php that creates the file:

(in admin.html..)

```
  $('#btn_refresh').click(function () {        
          $.ajax({
              url: "refresh.php"
          }).done(function (msg){
              alert(msg);
          }).fail(function () {
              alert('Error calling refresh script!');
          });
     });
```

(refresh.php contents...)

```
<?php     
    // I put the time inside the file, to help me know when something didn't work ok if the file gets stuck there
    $time = time();

    if(!touch('refreshcookie', $time)) {
        echo 'Something went wrong when trying to reload the webpage!';
    } else {
        echo 'Refresh order sent, this may take up to ten seconds';
    }
?>
```

3.- Finally, the checkrefresh.php checks if the file is there, and if is so responds and deletes it

```
<?php

    $imagefile = 'admin/refreshcookie';
    if (file_exists($imagefile))
    {
        unlink($imagefile);
        echo 1;
    }
    else
    {
        echo 0;
    }
?>
```

I would prefer to have an event instead of checking every x seconds, but it works...

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
@exec("sudo sh /var/www/refresh.sh", $output, $resultCode);
echo "<br>output: ";
var_dump($output);
echo "<br>resultCode: ";
var_dump($resultCode);
// remove the echoes/dumps later
?>
```

Something similar is working on my pi (3B+ => stretch)