# xdotool from Apache/PHP script

Tags: php, apache-httpd

With Raspbian Wheezy I could do the following without any problem through a PHP script run by Apache on the local Pi:

```
exec('env DISPLAY=:0 xdotool mousemove 20 10 2>&1', $output);
```

But now I have upgraded to the latest Raspbian Jessie it doesn't work anymore. I get the following error in `$output`:

```
No protocol specified
Error: Can't open display: (null)
Failed creating new xdo instance
```

Why is that and how do I fix it?

Note: The X session is running under the `pi` user and Apache is running under the `www-data` user.

Note: With *Wheezy* I used matchbox-window-manager and kweb browser, but now I use LXDE and Chromium that comes with *Jessie*. I don't think that should matter though, since as far as I recall xdotool also worked with LXDE in *Wheezy* (don't recall 100% for sure though).

[Here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/10571/refresh-chromium-browser-by-shell-script-with-xdotool-via-php) is a very similar question but the answer is a work-around that doesn't work for me.